# How to resolve CVE-2023-2976 vulnerability in Maven dependency com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre with Spring Security 6.2.1?

Tags: spring, maven, security, spring-security, saml

I recently encountered a vulnerability in my Maven project while adding a dependency to my pom.xml. The vulnerability is reported as CVE-2023-2976 with a severity level of High, indicating a "Files or Directories Accessible to External Parties" vulnerability. The problematic dependency is com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre.

Here are the specifics of my project setup:

- Spring Boot version: 3.2.2
- Spring Security version: 6.2.1

I attempted to mitigate the vulnerability by excluding the problematic dependency as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

but the problem still exist

Comment: Sorry Spring Boot Version 3.2.2  - Maven 3.9.5 - JDK 17.0.9

Comment: Than first step is to upgrade to SB 3.2.3... https://spring.io/blog/2024/02/22/spring-boot-3-2-3-available-now

Comment: @khmarbaise i upgrade to 3.2.3 but the problem still present

Comment: Has the guava project fixed the problem in a newer release?

Comment: Upgrade also the https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-saml2-service-provider to most recent version

Comment: thanks, I've solved the problem by adding these dependencies with their latest versions: om.google.guava & org.apache.santuario & org.bouncycastle

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the dependency by specifying the version to be greater than 32.0.1. The issue was fixed in it

Add the dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>32.1.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

The dependency you are excluding may or may not be bringing in guava.

you can generate the full dependency tree to find which dependeny is bringing in guava using

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

And exclude that in case its not needed or used by the project

Comment: thanks @Shiva, I've solved the problem by adding these dependencies with their latest versions: om.google.guava & org.apache.santuario & org.bouncycastle –